# Why my marquee textview in Android always marquee from begin when I refresh the view of other part?

Tags: android, android-listview, textview, expandablelistview, marquee

I want to use a textview which can marquee to show some information.There is an expandable listview below the textview which could get some information from the internet.   The problem is when I refresh some data in expandable listview , the textview which above the expandable listview could marquee from the begin of the text,like also refreshed.So I wonder why the textview performanced.It will cast a bad user experience.Thank you .

Comment: Why do `TextView`s even have a marquee option?

Comment: @DavidCowden  android:singleLine="true" 
              android:ellipsize="marquee"
              android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"  I write some property like that